# Insert image in column to Excel using Apache POI

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to insert an image into a cell in Excel. I've added pictures fine, but I still runs anywhere. I want to say that I want this column.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can set the row and column first then set the image.

```
try {

   Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
   Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("MYSheet");


   InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("path_to_image.jpg");

   byte[] imageBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);

   int pictureureIdx = workbook.addPicture(imageBytes, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);

   inputStream.close();

   CreationHelper helper = workbook.getCreationHelper();

   Drawing drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

   ClientAnchor anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();

   anchor.setCol1(1);
   anchor.setRow1(2);

   drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureureIdx);


   FileOutputStream fileOut = null;
   fileOut = new FileOutputStream("output.xlsx");
   workbook.write(fileOut);
   fileOut.close();
}catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: This always renders the image in the top left..!! How can I render in particular cell and how can I set the image width and height..?

Comment: I'm struggling with this too. I'd really like to create a cell, then put an image inside but that's not the way POI does it (probably microsoft's fault, not Apache's). The frustration comes when you sort your xlsx and all the data sorts but the images stay fixed, floating above the data...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54656080/anomalies-adding-png-in-xlsx-apache-poi-3-9

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems positioning image inside excel sheet. Here is the code which worked for me (Microsoft Excel 2019 version 2110)

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();

    Path imagePath = Path.of("...path to your image...");
    byte[] imageContent = Files.readAllBytes(imagePath);

    int pictureIndex = workbook.addPicture(imageContent, Workbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    // Option 1: use constructor, parameters 5-8 define starting cell-row and ending cell-row for image position
    // I have no clue what first 4 parameters are doing
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = new XSSFClientAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 6, 12);

    // Option 2: use Creation Helper and setters for defining starting and ending cell
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = workbook.getCreationHelper().createClientAnchor();
    anchor.setCol1(3);
    anchor.setRow1(3);
    anchor.setCol2(6);
    anchor.setRow1(12);

    XSSFDrawing drawingPatriarch = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
    drawingPatriarch.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);

    workbook.write(new FileOutputStream("output.xlsx"));
}
```

Maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Option 1 adds the picture into the workboo, but in my case, the image is stretched to the size of the cells unfortunately. How did you solve that?