# Anomalies adding PNG in xlsx - Apache POI 3.9

Tags: image, apache-poi, xlsx

I'm able to add pngs to my xlsx but with a few anomalies: On the last row (only), the image is overlaid on the previous row's image:

[image: Two images stacked on top of one another]

I suspect the anchoring:

```
    int pictureIndex = report.addPicture(curve, XSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG);
    anchor.setCol1(7);
    **anchor.setRow1(rowNumber-1);**
    anchor.setCol2(8);
    anchor.setRow2(rowNumber);
    drawing.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
```

But if I follow the examples I've seen, `anchor.setRow1(rowNumber)` then my images don't show at all.

Last, is there a way to put the image into a Cell (I would like the option to sort this spreadsheet)?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? I would expect `anchor.setRow1(rowNumber);...anchor.setRow2(rowNumber+1);` to work. But "is there a way to put the image into a Cell?": No, images as well as other shapes hover in a separate layer (the drawing) over the sheet and are only anchored to the cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trying many permutations of `setCol` and `setRow`, this eventually worked:

```
anchor.setCol1(col);
anchor.setRow1(row);
anchor.setCol2(col + 1);
anchor.setRow2(row + 1);
```